# For loop java making the output into 2 columns

Tags: java, loops

Hi I'm a beginner and I'm still learning and if someone could help me in this one thx in advance my code is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

and the output should be like this:

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9
```

Comment: Try giving some spaces in the `System.out.println()` and see how your code output changes. From there, you will be able to find how to bring the numbers to the next line.

Comment: So let's step through here a second: for every iteration (aka every time we run the code nside the loop), you're printing a line of information (`#println` will print the contents followed by `\n`). At the current moment, your code will simply print the value of `i`, followed by the newline. What kind of ways can you think to print the information you need, followed by that final newline?

Comment: you can just try givng a new next line character in java instead of println and try

Comment: This is not a homework-writing service. I see somebody has answered you. Do you feel better having cheated? So instead of learning on your own, you took somebody else's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *next line* only for odd numbers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        System.out.format("%2d", i);
    else
        System.out.format(" %2d\n", i);
}
```

**Output:**

```
 0  1
 2  3
 4  5
 6  7
 8  9
```

***P.S.** For more general usage, I would extract it into separate method*

```
public static void printTwoColumns(int min, int max) {
    int width = String.valueOf(max).length();

    for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
        String str = String.format("%" + width + 'd', i);

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(str);
        else {
            System.out.print(' ');
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.print(i);
  System.out.println(++i);
}
```

The first print uses the current i value and using System.out.print.
The second
print is using println so it goes one line down and also takes ++i so it will advance i by 1 and will also print the new value.

Each loop iteration is printing two values and advances i by total of 2.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can either do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){  
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        System.out.print(i); //Only for evens
    }else{
        System.out.println(i);  //Only for odds
    }
}
```

Or you could simplify it even more with something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i += 2){
    System.out.println(i + " " + (i + 1));
}
```